# How can I add more elements inside jquery.sumoselect plugin select list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sumoselect.js

I want to add more elements inside a list with multiple select checkboxes, but when I add more elements, they appear outside the list.

This is the code I want to put in:

```
<div class="select-box-style right">
    <div class="your-list-title">Your Lists</div>
    <select multiple="multiple" class="md_what_get right SlectBox">
        <option selected value="electronics">Electronics</option>
        <option value="games">Video Games</option>
        <option value="books">Books</option>
        <option value="others">Others</option>
    </select>
    <div class="add-list-box">
        <input type="text" class="input-add-list" />
        <label class="label-spcbtn-blue spr">Add</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want the select option to be displayed like this:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: what have you done so for??

Comment: You might need to add `css` too!!

Comment: @ozil i want this for a list like the picture
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0tbAXwjk3SzTzN6Y2tWaE1kcEU/edit

Comment: @GuruprasadRao yes but not now i want to put this element inside the list befor add css style the elements is outside

Answer (score 0):

As per your comments if you want to put it inside list you can do it as below:

**Put it as first element:**

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/x2y2dhkt/1/)**

```
$('.spr').on('click',function(){
    if($('.input-add-list').val().trim()!=='')
    {
        $('<option value="'+$('.input-add-list').val().trim()+'">'+$('.input-add-list').val().trim()+'</option>').insertBefore('.SlectBox option:first');
    }
});
```

**Put it as last element**

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/x2y2dhkt/)**

```
$('.spr').on('click',function(){
    if($('.input-add-list').val().trim()!=='')
    {
        $('.SlectBox').append('<option value="'+$('.input-add-list').val().trim()+'">'+$('.input-add-list').val().trim()+'</option>');
    }
});
```

> **If possible change your label `Add` to button**

**Update**

Use your native `plugin` method as below:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/x2y2dhkt/2/)**

```
$('.spr').on('click',function(){
    if($('.input-add-list').val().trim()!=='')
    {
        $('select.SlectBox')[0].sumo.add($('.input-add-list').val().trim());
    }
});
```

Comment: i put it like this:
` <script type="text/javascript">
                    $('.spr').on('click',function(){
    if($('.input-add-list').val().trim()!=='')
    {
        $('<option value="'+$('.input-add-list').val().trim()+'">'+$('.input-add-list').val().trim()+'</option>').insertBefore('.SlectBox option:first');
    }
});
                    </script>`

befor select
and the secont script after select element
but is not working!?!

Comment: Did you get how to add it??

Comment: the you see the change?

Comment: is not working 
look ignore the button label "add" as a button look her as a simple div
and ignore .spr like a event click is not click just for see it

Comment: i want just put the element inside list like the image in my question

Comment: @Machine my bad.. a slight change. Updated the answer with demo. Check and let me know!!

Comment: no not like this look the list alright? befor electronics i want put "your list" and the input and button after others all this inside the <select > element

Comment: you can look on dem the element i want inside is outside the list

Comment: if you have another way to design this list tell me please like the image on my question

Comment: there are any script to add div to select tag

Comment: You cannot add div to `select` tag

Comment: So you want the design of the select list which is in the image right??

Comment: yes i want to design of select list like the image, can you help me for that?

Comment: Then you cannot do it using this plugin as the plugin doens't have option to display multiple select in the manner you want!! You might need to find some plugin which creates similar design and then you can append list however you want!!

Comment: if you enter the javascript file for plugin you find this line O.optDiv = $('<div class="optWrapper">');  how can i use this code to add new div with custom class ??

Comment: @Rao , useful reply. Thank you. regarding the adding items with 'plugin method' could you please explain how to add the item with specifying 'value' and 'text' ? thanks.

Comment: Anytime!! Post you answer and accept it so that it will be useful to others in future! Happy Coding.. :)