# How to customize Jquery.sumoselect plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sumoselect.js

I use the [jQuery SumoSelect plugin](https://github.com/HemantNegi/jquery.sumoselect), and I want to customize the `select` tag to custom design.

This is the code:

```
<div class="select-box-style right">
    <div class="your-list-title">Your Lists</div>
    <select multiple="multiple" class="md_what_get right SlectBox">
        <option selected value="electronics">Electronics</option>
        <option value="games">Video Games</option>
        <option value="books">Books</option>
        <option value="others">Others</option>
    </select>
    <div class="add-list-box">
        <input type="text" class="input-add-list"/>
        <label class="label-spcbtn-blue spr" >Add</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to customize the plugin like this image:

[image]

How can I achieve this?

**More information about the plugin:**

> Neither SumoSelect or MultipleSelect (as is) supports the feature you
>   are looking at. But, first, some clarification needed:
>
> `<select>` boxes are a standard HTML tag, that accepts no other tags
>   than `<optgroup>` or `<option>`. see here:
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select
>
> SumoSelect and MultipleSelect are both Javascript plugins that
>   "converts" real selects into custom built `<div>` tags, with javascript
>   to handle the logic. That said, you can either modify/extend those
>   plugins to create the desired  or you can build your own
>   "`<select>` into `<div>` converter".
>
> But, for the sake of simplicity, you could just create a `<div>` with
>   all the desired functionality, using regular plain old checkboxes, and
>   hiding/displaying the whole `<div>` according to your UX flow/needs.

Comment: Where did you get the "more information" part? And how is this not a duplicate of [your own question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30665086/how-i-can-to-add-more-element-inside-jquery-sumoselect-plugin-select-list)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a duplicate of your own question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30665086/how-i-can-to-add-more-element-inside-jquery-sumoselect-plugin-select-list. Please edit the original question instead of asking it twice.

Comment: i need help, help me not tell me is duplicate i just need someone help me

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro can you help me on my question why people focus on duplicate and not focus to try help

Comment: i want a help i want cry